# use ajax to call php to write timestamp to file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to call a function in javascript to write to a text file.  This function uses ajax to to run some code in a php file.  All my code seems to be working fine, but I havent gotten any output (If the file doesn't exist, I want it to be created when the php code runs).  Everything is being run locally and must be run in chrome.  I've found some other people with similar questions, but I wasn't able to apply those solutions.  I am very new so please be explicit.  Also, if there is a better way to do this (get the system timestamp and write/append to a text file) I am more than open.  I just need to record the timestamp whenever a particular javascript function is called.  In addition, I would like to eventually pass a string from my running javascript to be saved with each timestamp (the string is determined by the running javascript).  Note that running in "Data: running" is a dummy variable.  Eventually this will be used to pass a string.

im using this script to use ajax (in html script)

```
script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"

javascript code..... call recordTone().... javascript code


function recordTone() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "file:///C:/Users/ryan/Desktop/New%20folder/saveTimeStamp.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: running,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

`saveTImeStamp1.php` in entirety

```
<?php
    $my_file = 'session1.txt';
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '$my_file);
    $data = microtime();
    fwrite($handle, $data);
    fclose($handle);
    echo "YES";  
?>
```

Comment: Are you running a php server? Your "file://" doesn't look quite right.

Comment: As Ed Heal and Xymostech said, you need a web server. Almost everyone uses Xampp or Wamp for developing PHP applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a web server and then have a URL to it. Easy to install Apache and PHP Like "Ed Heal" said...

or you can use web service to call you procedure/function ...

```
function recordTone() {
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "localhost/yousite/saveTimeStamp.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: running,
    success: function(msg){
      alert(msg);
    }          
  });
}
```

look at 'url', change to your local site...

Comment: much appreciated to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need a web server and then have a URL to it. Easy to install Apache and PHP

Not

```
file:///C:/Users/ryan/Desktop/New%20folder/saveTimeStamp.php
```

As this will not work

Comment: This is the only thing that I have wrong with my code?  I have no intention of running this online.  This is will only be run locally on my PC.  Ultimately all I want to do is save the system timestamp to a textfile using javascript.

Comment: You can run a web server on you PC. 127.0.0.1 or loopback will be the IP address. Use the firewall to prevent external access.

Answer (score 0):

Install XAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), and then reference your file relatively.  If the html file is in C:/Users/ryan/Desktop/New%20folder/, just change the url to "saveTimeStamp.php".

Another option if you don't want to install your own webserver is to purchase some hosting online, from somewhere like http://www.arvixe.com/.